# how to use another controller method in ember

Tags: ember.js

im' trying to use a method which is in application.js, is these a controller.
it has a method called isAuthenticated which return if a user is login or not.

in my application.hbs it works fine,
but when i call it in my posts/new.hbs it always return false.
why it?

my application controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import App from '../app';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  authManager: App.AuthManager,

  currentUser: function() {
    return App.AuthManager.get('apiKey.user');
  }.property('authManager.apiKey'),

  isAuthenticated: function() {
    return App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated();
  }.property('authManager.apiKey'),
});
```

solutions?

Comment: How are you calling it from your template?

Comment: does `App.AuthManger.isAuthenticated()` change when `authManager.apiKey` is changed?  maybe when you set `apiKey` it's false, and then `this.isAuthenticated()` isn't re-evaluated